# Separate copy of static member(defined in a shared library) inside executable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors

I am building a `C++` project on my Mac system. I have static library `libA.a` which is linked to a Mac framework (`B.framework`). I am dynamically linking `B.framework` with my executable `exe`.

There is a `static` member defined in a class defined in `libA.a`

```
class MyClass {
    static MyType* myVar;
public:
    print() {
        //prints address of myVar(&myVar) value
    }
};
```

I observed that at runtime when I call the `print()` method via code in `B.framework` and via code in `exe`, both print different values of `&myVar`.

It looks like `exe` has a separate copy of `myVar`. What I expected and wanted to achieve is to have a single copy of myVar? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You would need to have your dynamic framework *export* the class (and, thus, its static members) and your executable *import* the class. How to go about this will depend - to an extent - on your compiler and/or target platform. Can you give some details on those?

Comment: I exported the symbol by adding it file and exporting via -exported_symbols_list flag. How to import it in executable?

Comment: That depends on your compiler/environment/platform. Typically, you have a macro defined as "export" for the dynamic library/framework and as "import" for the consuming executable, then use that macro as an attribute on your class. On Windows, for a DLL/EXE interface you would have `#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllexport)` or `#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllimport)` and then add that `DLLEXP` to your class declaration, like `DLLEXP class MyClass {...`